# Как переставить параметры URL с помощью mod_rewrite?

Tags: ajax, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

Саппорт на хостинге сказал, что `mod_rewrite` мне в помощь, но я не знаю и не могу понять, что я должен сделать после долгих дней бессонницы.

В общем, если зайти на сайт вот так: `mysite.ru/?param=123`, то `ajax` запрос посылает запрос на обработчик не по ссылке `mysite.ru/resource/php/first_load.pnp`, а по `mysite.ru/?param=123resource/php/first_load.pnp`.

Я прочитал мануал, но так и не понял саму конкретику.

Можете помочь с примером?

Comment: Кажется что проще (и правильнее) починить то место откуда отправляется запрос

Comment: @AlexeyTen Вы знаете, я так и сделал... Я посмотрел свою функцию `ajax`, где нашел строчку `xhr.open('post', window.location.href + '/resource/php/...', true)`. Оказалось, это я сам себе придумал проблему